# No Route Found in Symfony 2.2.1 after Generation of CRUD

Tags: symfony, routes

Hell friends. I am working on a symfony 2 project where I have to add a crud operation. Folder structure is src->M2Catalyst->M2MatchCut and Utilities. Under M2MatchCut folder I have a StoreBundle. Where I am trying to generate a new crud like as follows:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle:Partner
"write" actions [no]? y
Configuration format (yml, xml, php, or annotation) [annotation]:annotation
Routes prefix [/partner]:null
Do you confirm generation [yes]?y
```

My routing.yml as follows

```
   m2_catalyst_m2_match_cut_dubit:
    resource: "@M2CatalystM2MatchCutDubitBundle/Controller/"
    prefix:   /

m2_catalyst_m2_match_cut_store:
    resource: "@M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix:   /product


m2_catalyst_m2_match_cut_match_cut:
    resource: "@M2CatalystM2MatchCutMatchCutBundle/Controller"
    prefix:   /matchcut
    type:     annotation

m2_catalyst_m2_match_cut_api:
    resource: "@M2CatalystM2MatchCutApiBundle/Controller"
    prefix:   /api
    type:     annotation

homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

m2_catalyst_m2_match_cut_youtube_api:
    resource: "@M2CatalystM2MatchCutYoutubeApiBundle/Controller"
    prefix:   /youtube
    type:     annotation


fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

# Only login and basic security at first

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

m2_catalyst_m2_match_cut_user:
    resource: "@M2CatalystM2MatchCutUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

m2_catalyst_m2_match_cut_home:
    resource: "@M2CatalystM2MatchCutHomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /


sonata_page_cache:
    resource: '@SonataCacheBundle/Resources/config/routing/cache.xml'
    prefix: /

# app/config/routing.yml
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /

gallery:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/gallery.xml'
    prefix: /media/gallery

media:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/media.xml'
    prefix: /media
```

But when I am trying to access M2Catalyst/web/app_dev.php/m2matchcut/store/movie it's says No route found for "GET /m2matchcut/store/movie"

What is going wrong, can anyone help?

My Controller class PartnerController as follows:

```
<?php

namespace M2Catalyst\M2MatchCut\StoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use M2Catalyst\M2MatchCut\StoreBundle\Entity\Partner;
use M2Catalyst\M2MatchCut\StoreBundle\Form\PartnerType;

/**
 * Partner controller.
 *
 * @Route("/partner")
 */
class PartnerController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Partner entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="partner")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle:Partner')->findAll();

        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new Partner entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="partner_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle:Partner:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity  = new Partner();
        $form = $this->createForm(new PartnerType(), $entity);
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('partner_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Partner entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="partner_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Partner();
        $form   = $this->createForm(new PartnerType(), $entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Partner entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="partner_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle:Partner')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Partner entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Partner entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="partner_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle:Partner')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Partner entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createForm(new PartnerType(), $entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Edits an existing Partner entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="partner_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle:Partner:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle:Partner')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Partner entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createForm(new PartnerType(), $entity);
        $editForm->bind($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('partner_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
    /**
     * Deletes a Partner entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="partner_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle:Partner')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Partner entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('partner'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Partner entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id))
            ->add('id', 'hidden')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your controller class

Comment: updated the question above@ Andrzej

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong.

If you want render indexAction from your controller, this path should work for that route configuration:

```
.../app_dev.php/movie/partner
```

Comment: Actually I tried to make another crud named Movie. and tried to define that with prefix / in routing. Changed that after in /movie. I delete this part of code now from routing.yml
`m2_catalyst_m2_match_cut_store_movie:
    resource: "@M2CatalystM2MatchCutStoreBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix:   /movie`